# ng-class using classes from variable under condition

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I am using a directive and want to use `ng-class` in a way that I could output multiple classes (which are stored in a variable) under certain condition.

```
<div ng-if="showIcons" ng-class="{state.icon: showIcons}"></div>
```

```
$scope.state = { 
    icon: 'icon-cross-outline color-brand-danger'
};
```

Unfortunately this is not working.

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using?

Comment: Angular ver 1.5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ternary operator in `ng-class`, could you try the following?

```
<div ng-if="showIcons" ng-class="showIcons ? state.icon : null"></div>
```

### [Demo on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6Jrm36bYWbuWc69UtYCp?p=preview)

Comment: @be-codified On this Plunker, [**it works for me**](http://plnkr.co/edit/6Jrm36bYWbuWc69UtYCp?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Perhaps my problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: @be-codified Yes, I think. Try to hard-code your classes. Does it works? Is `state.icon` a String? Are you sure your classes exists in CSS? Play with my Plunker, maybe you will fix your issue from it. :-)

Comment: It works if I try to hardcode, so it must be something with value of `state.icon` :) Will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do more complicated stuff via binding a function to the `ng-class` see my [plnker](https://plnkr.co/edit/qZaN4fHQYm52E5vih7wp?p=preview)

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('hey', []);

app.controller('TheController', [function () {
  this.title = "hey"
  this.shouldApply = true;

  this.canApplyClass = function () {
    if (this.shouldApply == true) {
      return 'happy sad other';
    }

    return '';
  }
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="hey">
  <div ng-controller="TheController as c">
    <h1 ng-class="c.canApplyClass()">{{c.title}}</h1>  
  </div>
</body>
```

I prefer this approach because you can get complicated in the function - and even have access to other services.